# Format display of a floating number to a fixed length

Tags: python-3.x

I'm displaying share prices, and need to display all floating numbers to an exact width of 8 places, with a zero representing the ones place.  Some prices per share are quite large, and some will be very small.

For example,  182.1234567890  and 0.12345678901 would respectively format to:
182.1234 and 0.123456

Its not important to align the decimals.
What is important is that the width of the output is always 8 spaces long (including decimal).

There are many formatting questions here, but unfortunately didn't see one that addresses this specific question.

This is for a bot that returns price queries.
I've tried format strings, but they require I set a specific length for precision of the decimal.  Decimal precision is not as important as total width of the number value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this as well:

```
def FormatIt(number, desired_length):
    mantissa_length = desired_length - len(str(int(number))) - 1

    return ('{:#.%df}' % (mantissa_length, )).format(number)
```

Output:

```
>>> FormatIt(182.1234567890, 8)
'182.1235'
>>> FormatIt(0.12345678901, 8)
'0.123457'
```

Comment: works also with a single `format` use (instead of mixing with `%` formatting): `'{:#.{man}f}'.format(number, man=mantissa_length)`

Comment: @Tomerikoo, hey, that's pretty great, I'm definitely using this in my code from now on!

Answer (score 2):

Format strings provide a solution when you want a certain number of decimal places, and they have to because otherwise you have to implement some complex logic to figure out where the decimal place even is.

But making sure the *width of the output* is always 8 spaces long is easy - just truncate the string after the 8th character:

```
str(my_float)[:8]
```

Or if you need to print strings longer than length 8 if the number is large enough,

```
str(my_float)[:8] if my_float < 10000000 else str(int(my_float))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
l=[182.1234567890, 0.12345678901]
for i in l:
    print(str(i)[:8])
```

Answer (score 0):

This function should do it:

```
def rounds(num):
  num = len(str(int(a)))
  points = 7 - num if num < 7 else 0
  return f'{a:.{points}f}'

rounds(12345)
#12345.00
rounds(182.1234567890)
#182.1234
```